# Docker gradle: how to resolve the location of maven local repository

Tags: docker, maven, gradle, local, maven-repository

Docker gradle: how to specify the location of maven local repository? e.g.,

On windows host, the mavenLocal repository is at:

```
C:\Users\username\.m2\repository
```

When runing gradle in Dockerfile, the expected mavenLocal repository is at:

```
/root/.m2/repository
```

As the result, Dockerfile

```
...
RUN gradle build
```

Could not resolve artifacts that are in the mavenLocal.

The repository is huge, and could not copy it to the image.
Two questions:

1. Inside dockerfile, is there a way to get user.home directory on host?
2. Inside dockerfile, Is there a way to tell gradle the location of mavenLocal repository? any ENV?

Comment: You need to add the local repo to the repositories block in the gradle build file itself.
`
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
`